# Are Open JDK and JDK7 the same thing?

Tags: java, java-7

Are Open JDK and JDK7 the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between Oracle JDK and Open JDK and garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open JDK is a free (but not certified) implementation of the JLS (java language specification) where JDK7 is the next version of Sun's JDK which is currently 1.6 (or just Java 6 as the marketing devision of Sun called it).

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK was initially based only on the JDK 7.0 version of the Java platform.
Since February 15, 2008, there are two separate OpenJDK projects:

- The main [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) project, which is based on the JDK 7.0 version of the Java platform
- The [JDK 6 project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/), which provides an Open-source version of Java 6.0.

I hope this clears the confusion a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Solaris<-->OpenSolaris situation, viz. there's an open-source project with as much code as possible; the fixes get transferred back to the main software, which the vendor supports and sells.  OpenJDK is a project.  OpenJDK version 7 and JDK7 appear to be largely but not exactly the same (per [here](http://java.sun.com/features/jdk/7/)).