# Will one FileOutputStream constructor call another one?

Tags: java, file, constructor, fileoutputstream

I looked on the java docs for FileOutputStream
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)
and saw that one constructor took just a file object and another one took a file object and a boolean append. Will the first constructor just call the second constructor with false passed as append? Java docs didn't talk about this

Comment: Does it matter? Whether it calls the other constructor or not, the effects are the same.

Comment: The java source is available and one can always view to understand the underlying implementation.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: Curiosity, just want to see how the constructors are implemented

Comment: Here is [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#FileOutputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cboolean%29) it calls two argument constructor with `false` as second value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (the Oracle JDK) `FileOutputStream` makes use of constructor chaining. This is simply an implementation detail and you should not rely on it unless referred to in the API specification (javadoc).

[Here's the OpenJDK JDK implementation which also chains constructor calls.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileOutputStream.java?av=f)

Comment: It is not correct to talk about Oracle's JDK and OpenJDK's JDK.  They are developed by the same (Oracle) team; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22358234/139985.  The copyright for "OpenJDK's JDK" is owned by Oracle.

Comment: @StephenC Sure, but aren't they two different implementations even if they are owned by the same team? How would I refer to the Java JDK you get [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)?

Comment: 1) Well yes and no.  In fact, they are almost identical.  2) I would refer to them as the "The Oracle JDK" or "The Hotspot JDK" versus "The OpenJDK JDK".  (Or Hotspot versus OpenJDK.)  Note - no use of the possessive.

Answer (score 0):

Following happens if you use constructor without boolean.

```
FileOutputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
 this(file, false);
}
```

Normally in these kind of scenarios values true or false are decided based on most used operation. So if you are writing on OutputStream you will be creating  a new file most of the time, hence it passes `false` as default.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

yes that's true. The *FileOutputStream(File file)* invokes *FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)* setting append=false. For your reference, the source code looks like

```
public FileOutputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(file, false);
}


    public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
    throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkWrite(name);
    }
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.fd = new FileDescriptor();
    this.append = append;

    fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
    open(name, append);
}
```

Normally, JavaDoc does not say internal details. It is for the API description only.