# Get java classes source code

Tags: java

I want to get java classes source code  in netbeans .
For example linkedlist
How i can get source code of this class just using a software  that you can use it for coding and run java codes like netbeans

Comment: Is there a decompiler for the program you are using?

Comment: hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258944/where-is-the-src-zip-for-jdk8u40,

Comment: In NetBeans, left click on desired class and chose Navigate -> Go to source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the path of JDK in build path instead of JRE, it will show you source code when open any JDK class.

Comment: may you describe more for me

Comment: Please see [https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html] Setting the Target JDK in a Project