# Java Netbeans intuitive parameter names

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, parameters

I apologise if the title is vague or confusing, English is not my mother tongue and I am really giving my best to keep the grammar and spelling correct.

I was checking out how DriverManager and JDBC in Java works so I tried setting up a connection to my database. I use Netbeans for my Java coding. 
I tried using the getConnection method but I was confused by the order of the parameters the function takes. I got it all to work eventually but one thing I noticed was that for me the parameter names are displayed basically like this: "String string, String string1, String string2" in the "tooltip" for all the different overloads.

While I see that for certain people and in the Oracle docs website for DriverManager, the parameters are displayed as: "String url, String user, String password". I realise I can read the order in the javadoc, but I think it would really be helpful if the parameter names were for me like that too.

So instead of having "String string, String string1, String string2" I want to have have "String url, String user, String password".

Incase you are not sure of what I am talking about, Here is a screenshot:

[image: Parameters tooltip]

Does anyone have an idea on how to enable this? How to change it ? Tried googling but to no success. That might be because of my bad english and due to the terminology being quite off.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Re "This is the method-signature thought up and programmed by the developers of this DriverManager", that is not correct. **DriverManager** is a JDK class, and by viewing the source code you can see that the parameters for getConnection() were given meaningful names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. This is what I see in NetBeans 8.2:

[image: prompting]

Have you set **Sources** and **JavaDoc** for the JDK you are using? To check, go to **Tools > Java Platforms** and select the platform you are using, then look at the **Sources** and **Javadoc** tabs. This is what I have:

[image: prompting2]

If they are not set then try setting them to see if that fixes the problem. If they are set can you update the OP with a screen shot of what you have?

Comment: Okay so I checked my source and javadoc and compared them with yours. They are not the same. Mine look like this :

https://imgur.com/a/BMjFD

Comment: I believe the auto-complete only relies on presence of the sources, not on the javadoc links.

Comment: OK. Your **Javadoc** tab looks good, but you need to add **src.zip** to your **Sources** tab. If you have a zip file named **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\src.zip** then click the **Add JAR/Folder** button to add it. Then try **DriverManager.get** again to see if the parameters have better names.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do as well. I just figured that it was worth checking both tabs to avoid a follow up question on Javadoc problems.

Comment: I checked my jdk1.8.0_151 folder and it has only javafx-src.zip.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic Then you should reinstall the JDK and make sure to install the sources

Comment: @BenjaminBajic As Mark suggests, it looks like you may have chosen not to install the source during the installation of 151. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258944/where-is-the-src-zip-for-jdk8u40 where someone had a similar problem with 8u40.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to add **src.zip** without reinstalling, unless you happen to have another copy of **src.zip** lying around from some earlier release of Java 8;  that should work fine. But if you are going to reinstall JDK I suggest going with the latest version rather than 151.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic It looks like there may be an easy way to get **src.zip** after all! Pretend to reinstall 151 but do not go past the first screen, then follow the instructions here: https://bgasparotto.com/extract-src-zip-jdk-installer

Comment: @skomisa thank you so much! It worked perfectly. Now my parameters actually have names and its soo much easier. It worked perfectly. Thank you once more.

Comment: I am now getting the same issue, just with other methods. The fix above did not work for this case.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic OK. Has anything significant been modified since it worked? For example, have you possibly upgraded NetBeans and/or the JDK, or are they unchanged? If you provide the name of a class/method that does not work now, I will check it in my environment.

Comment: @skomisa no, nothing. My DriverManager class still works fine, but example extending DefaultHandler class when using SAX, methods such as startElement, endElement etc all have very different names. I am attaching a link to a picture here : https://imgur.com/a/JFc1kRz. The bottom one is how it should look like, while the top one is how it looks for me.

Comment: @BenjaminBajic Strange - autocomplete with **DefaultHandler** is working for me. To be clear, in your class that extends **DefaultHandler**, if you place the cursor over the literal value _"startElement"_ in your override of the **startElement()** method, and then right-click and select _"Go to Super Implementation"_ from the context menu, what do you see in the file named **DefaultHandler.java** that opens? Do the parameter names for **DefaultHandler.startElement()** look correct, as in the bottom half of your screen shot, or wrong as in the top half of your screen shot?