# What can I do with Oracle JDK that I can not do with OpenJDK

Tags: jvm, java

After I read this interesting question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection), I am thinking:
"What can I do with Oracle JDK that I can not do with OpenJDK?". Is just a specific example, like a implementation that is not possible with OpenJDK and is possible with Oracle JDK, to experience in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, there is nothing one can do that the other cannot. However, Oracle has stated [citation needed] that OpenJDK will be updated more rapidly, while Oracle JDK adds some proprietary components. These additional components are not language constructs, merely additions or reimplementations.

An example of such a reimplementation (as requested) is the [JRockit JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), which is a proprietary implementation of the JVM itself.

An example of a component not included in the OpenJDK is [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html).

As can be seen from these examples, the commercial features do not provide any language constructs or functionality that cannot be achieved with the OpenJDK. An exhaustive list of commercial features in the Oracle JDK can be found in [Oracle's product documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html)

Comment: *For the most part, there is nothing one can do that the other cannot*. I have read similar statements over and over. Can you give an example of something you can do with one, but not the other? Or maybe give an example in different behaviour?