# Unit Test and Source Code for Java classes

Tags: java

I am curious to understand how Java tests its APIs. Let's say,I am interested in the class ConcurrentHashMap, will there be any unit tests for this class? If so, is it available for public?

Comment: Which implementation of Java do you mean?  If you mean OpenJDK, I would suspect you could find these (there is a `test` directory in their source at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d).  If you mean Oracle's Java, then I doubt you'll have so much luck.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to run unit tests on a class within the platform libraries.  Part of the reason that there are platform libraries is so that you'll have a set of utility classes that have already been tested for you.  Many of the library classes have more development and testing hours than you could possibly afford to spend on any class yourself.

Comment: I mean't Oracle's Java. But good to know about the tests for open jdk.

Comment: I am not planning to run these unit tests, was just curious to understand how the Java APIs are tested.

Comment: @soong what you have posted is brilliant resource and I think that's what he was after . You should post it as answer. I will give you a vote if nothing else :)

Answer (score 9):

When you say "**Java**" you probably mean the **Java Development Kit** (JDK), which comes as **[OracleJDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)** and **[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)** (OracleJDK is essentially OpenJDK with [a few extras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358234/1290264)). OpenJDK is open-source; and the source code for all of its projects can be found here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/

In particular, here is a browsable version of the **[jdk7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/)** project directory.

---

> I am curious to understand how Java tests its APIs. Let's say,I am interested in the class ConcurrentHashMap, will there be any unit tests for this class? If so, is it available for public?

Yes, for a list of all jdk7 tests look in **[jdk7/jdk/test](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/test)**.

If you are interested in `ConcurrentHashMap` tests, look in **[jdk7/jdk/test/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/test/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap)**:

---

**NOTE:** The JDK tests may look a bit awkward because it does not use JUnit, it uses [JTreg](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jtreg/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Any class packaged inside jdk like ConcurrentHashMap is tested and you don't need to worry almost all the cases. If you implementing a well defined interfaces then there are test cases available which can run against your API and check whether it's complacency. In addition if you define a new API which you will expose, you have to write your test cases using JUnit or TestNg. Here the purpose of your test cases should be checking whether your API giving expected results. If you cover all the combination of using your API then you can identify when there is a regression.

Offtopic : Integration testing suppose to test the whole project when all the components are integrated.

**[Update]** If you really need to test ConcurrentHashMap you can use a sample project which uses ConcurrentHashMap, please keep in mind that you better choose multi-thread project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to get the source (and thus the testing code) for Oracle's Java.  However, since OpenJDK theoretically follows the same specifications for behavior as Oracle Java (at least for all the parts of it that I'm familiar with), you could perhaps use their unit tests to test your library.  The source for OpenJDK's `jdk8` can be browsed [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d) (see the `test` directory for tests), and you can find other versions of java at their main page.

However, as Erranda points out, you should really ask yourself if you want to test the existing libraries.  They are probably more thoroughly tested than anything you'll end up writing already, and unless you want to recompile Java from source after finding an issue (which could lead to compatibility problems), what good would finding a bug in the libraries do?