# Java - is it free?

Tags: java

We've been using Java to build our enterprise software (not embedded) for years and redistributing the JRE to our customers freely.
Recently Oracle representatives approached us at a tradeshow offering their services.
After a couple of calls with our engineers they started claiming that we need to pay them for Java because our software is not "General Purpose".

So, a few questions:

1. Has anyone else encountered this?
2. Has anyone switched to OpenJDK?
3. Any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: Never heard of this. I worked in different companies which don't make software for "General Purpose". Never had to pay anything. Are you 100% sure they are _real_ Oracle representatives?

Comment: If you had told them you were using OpenJDK up front, I'm sure they'd have freaked out a bit.  Further to that, I doubt they have any legal standing anyway...double check the license you agreed to with Oracle when downloading the JDK and be sure that legal is on board with what's going on.

Comment: see https://java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml "*Yes, you can provide Java with your software provided you abide by the terms and conditions of Java binary code license.*"

Comment: Consult a lawyer to make sense of their license terms: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Comment: Why would you redistribute the JDK?

Comment: @Kayaman Microsoft won't permit vendors to pre-install Java on retail computers, generally.

Comment: @VGR Are you referring to the JRE or the JDK? I can't imagine anyone pre-installing the JDK on retail computers.

Comment: @Kayaman Oh… my mistake, this is about the JDK, not the JRE.  You're right of course;  there's no reason for a JDK to be on a retail machine.

Comment: You're right - I meant the JRE (not JDK)

Answer (score 5):

If my memory serves correctly, I vaguely remember reading somewhere that you are allowed to redistribute JRE with your apps, but not the JDK itself for free. Why would you want to distribute JDK anyways, unless you are building IDEs? Then of course, Oracle could step in and demand remuneration.

Comment: You wouldn't need it even for an IDE. Eclipse (for example) has its own compiler, so it doesn't require the JDK to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is also:

[**OpenJDK (Open Java Development Kit)** is a free and open source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)

Check the [Differences between Oracle JDK and Open JDK and garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection)