# How to uninstall openjdk on amazon ec2 micro instance running Redhat Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, oraclejdk

I have Installed OpenJdk on my redhat instance recently. Now am in need to go for Java Jdk. I saw some sites for replacement but none working for me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What's wrong with the OpenJDK? They're [practically the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection)...

Comment: I am installing Jboss AS but that doesn't support OpenJDK so i need to uninstall that and install Oracle JDK for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK , then written to the terminal.

```
alternatives --config java
```

Enter the number

I work in fedora , try it in Red Hat.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rtfpessoa/17752cbf7156bdf32c59 This helpme acheiving what i was looking for. Thank you all !!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot application is failed to start on AWS EC2 instance because of JDK old version is running on EC2 Instance. I have run following command to set updated version 1.8 from 1.7.
Follow command:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

To see which version of java was installed:

`rpm -qa | grep java` **OR** `rpm -qa | grep jdk`

**You get output like :**

```
javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.amzn2.noarch
python-javapackages-3.4.1-11.amzn2.noarch
java-11-amazon-corretto-headless-11.0.22+7-1.amzn2.x86_64
```

Then remove package using RPM or YUM:

```
yum remove java-11-amazon-corretto-headless-11.0.22+7-1.amzn2.x86_64
```

or

```
rpm -e java-11-amazon-corretto-headless-11.0.22+7-1.amzn2.x86_64
```