# Oracle JDK 1.6 and Open JDK 1.6

Tags: java, oraclejdk

I have been developing my application in the Oracle JDK 1.6 development environment. When I move it to a different environment the code started getting broken, until I figured out the culprit was the environment was configured to OpenJDK 1.6.

After I installed Oracle JDK 1.6 in the second environment everything looks alright. Out of curiosity, how does the same Java version implementation have this effect? Aren't these implementations for the same specification?

Comment: Without more detail on how the code broke it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Assuming that both are exactly the same, is incorrect. This may help to answer your question:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection)

Comment: Why are you using JDK 1.6, it's been EOL for several years now. It has known bugs and problems that won't ever be fixed, especially in the graphics/windowing API's.

Comment: Well I can't change that, It is a default in the company I am working on

Comment: In fairness to Yohannes, I am forced to use Java 6 at work, because of the code base's dependency on some library (not sure which one) which only works in 6.  It's disgusting, but I'm not in a position to change it.

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam - Tell us the company name so that we can short-sell their stocks :-)

Comment: @VGR there is no reason a j6 library won't work on a j7 or j8 system. That's one of the main selling points of the java ecosystem... in fact, where I work, we have some jar libs that were compiled back for j5 and we still use them just fine in our j7 and j8 environments.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Unless, of course, that library uses sun.\* or com.\* classes that don't exist in later versions.  Yes, it's a terrible practice.  They do it anyway.