# Openfire connection closed with internal error

Tags: java, ubuntu, xmpp, openfire, smack

So i have this code to connect to openfire

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();  

      config.setUsernameAndPassword(loginUser, passwordUser);
      config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
      config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
      config.setHost(serverAddress);
      config.setPort(5222);
      config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
      connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
  ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection).enableAutomaticReconnection();

      System.out.println("Reconnection enabled : " + ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection).isAutomaticReconnectEnabled());

      ConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
      connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```

but when i try to connect i get this error :

> org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: internal-server-error You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
>   
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1007)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:948)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:963)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

**EDIT :** Openfire's log :

Warn log :

```
2016.06.13 11:06:31 org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain - Unexpected exception from exceptionCaught handler. 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView; 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.roster.Roster.broadcastPresence(Roster.java:628) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.broadcastUpdate(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:309) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:163) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:138) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:202) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.handle(PresenceRouter.java:144) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.route(PresenceRouter.java:80) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:88) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager$ClientSessionListener.onConnectionClose(SessionManager.java:1267) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection.notifyCloseListeners(NIOConnection.java:266) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection.close(NIOConnection.java:248) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionHandler.java:162)
```

i tried to connect to a local openfire server(windows), i succeded, but I fail when i try to connect to an ubuntu openfre server.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To quote the Exception's message: "internal-server-error You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions".

Comment: First thing I did but wooh! Nothing found..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Openfire provides in-depth diagnostic log messages containing the reason a `internal-server-error` would be sent.

Comment: I've added the warn log

Comment: But not the relevant parts.

Comment: yeah sorry, check now

Comment: to me appears the java7/8 "issue" (https://community.igniterealtime.org/blogs/ignite/2016/03/21/openfire-402-released read the comment)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise : openfire needs oracle jre 8 NOT Openjdk

Comment: what about oracle jre 7?

Comment: I don't think that it matters if it's an Oracle JRE or OpenJRE. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection

Comment: Believe me, it does, at least that's what I experienced lately, with openjdk clients can't connect to server but when I changed to oracle's jre all went fine.

Comment: I faced same issue to run Openfire in Eclipse, basically there is a method signature changed on ConcurrentHashMap. To run it with Java7 I declared the maps as Interface (Map) and added some cast. But i now need to avoid the problem on real server, if possibile without install JRE8 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Openfire need Java 8 (or higher).

Comment: I can't contradict you but what about to not use OpenJDK? I'm really interested...

Comment: I've made no statements about using OpenJRE or any other Java 8 compliant runtime environment.

Comment: I know, but I know that you are an Openfire "admin" and I was referring about comments on official website (Guus der Kinderen 24 March) @Flow

Comment: Valid Point: I'd simply express this request in the ingiterealtime.org community forums.

Comment: well, i have the openjdk-8 and still the same error, i'm trying with oracle jdk

Comment: "Having" OpenJDK not automatically implies that Openfire is run with it. Did you verify that Openfire was started with openjdk-8?

Comment: Yep I've tried, and the server was installed, when I try connecting to server I get internal error.

Comment: And yep that was the only jre on server