# How to change the version of java installed in BOSS Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am trying to change java installed in boss Linux because am trying to install eclipse oxygen which needs java8. First I couldn't find where the jdk installed. Currently 1.7.0_73 installed. I just downloaded the tar.gz of jdk8. Extracted in a location. Setted java home and path pointing bin. But still am getting error during eclipse installation that version 1.8 is required.

Comment: Can you send a print of the error you are getting?
It sounds like the instance of eclipse you are trying to run is using the old Java pathing to JDK-7......

Comment: Yes exactly..it is showing that java installed is 1.7 73 required is 1.8 or above

Comment: How are you running eclipse ? Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Boss linux. Now its working. I started it from terminal. But if i double click it, it shows the error i reported. Is there any way to find where that 1.7 java installed? I tried to search it, but i couldnt find it.

Answer (score 2):

Well as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Operating_System_Solutions) states that

```
BOSS Linux is an "LSB certified" Linux distribution :
     the software has been certified by the Linux Foundation
     for compliance with the Linux Standard Base standard.
     BOSS Linux is derived from Debian Linux.
```

Note that It is derived from **`Debian Linux`** and uses `apt` to handle packages for updates or upgrades. On that note, you just have to use `apt`
command to upgrade to version you want.

#### Installing java version `1.8` by installing `OpenJDK v8`

To install java version 1.8 (OpenJDK v8), type following on terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

If you only want to install the Java Runtime Environment :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Feel free to add-in more details to the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me what is openjdk? Is that specific to linux?

Comment: No openjdk is not specific to linux. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk) to know more about openjdk and oracle-jdk.