# Java version history: what does "2019 (commercial)" mean?

Tags: java

When I looked at the history of Java versions I've seen that 8th version will be commercial in 2019 and will be non-commercial in 2020. I didn't get what these mean. And besides please explain what does "vendor specific" mean?
[image]

Comment: `vendor specific` means that every vendor has it's own policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be quoting the [Wikipedia Java history page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history). On that page it says:

> ...and "end of public updates" for Java 8 is scheduled for January 2019 for commercial use, and not earlier than December 2020 for non-commercial use.[[3]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html)

...which seems fairly clear in terms of the "(Commercial)" vs. "(Non-commercial)" part of that chart. It links to the Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap, which has these definitions:

> **Commercial Users**. Commercial Users are entities other than Oracle Customers that use Java SE for business, commercial or production purposes as part of a Java application delivered by a third party or developed internally.
>
> **Personal Users**. Personal Users are individuals who use Java SE on personal desktops or laptops. Personal users include individuals using Oracle Java SE to develop applications for hobby or educational purposes, play games or run consumer productivity applications.

...and further down it says that "Commercial User End of Public Updates" is January 2019 and "Personal User End of Public Updates" is December 2020.

"Vendor specific" means exactly that: Different vendors (Oracle, OpenJDK) will have their own policy for when extended support of Java SE 11 ends.

Comment: Thanks to this, I've learnt that OpenJDK is open source java and before 2015 it has been very slow. But Google had decided to use OpenJDK for Android. Thank you for "vendor specific" explanation. OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK https://stackoverflow.com/a/38685948/104085

Answer (score 1):

The dates are when support ceases.

The difference between commercial and non-commerical is explained here:

[Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html)

To quote:

> Commercial Users. Commercial Users are entities other than Oracle
>   Customers that use Java SE for business, commercial or production
>   purposes as part of a Java application delivered by a third party or
>   developed internally.
>
> Personal Users. Personal Users are individuals who use Java SE on
>   personal desktops or laptops. Personal users include individuals using
>   Oracle Java SE to develop applications for hobby or educational
>   purposes, play games or run consumer productivity applications.

Personal = Non-commercial