# Pentaho server login problems after java JDK change from Oracle to Amazon Coretto

Tags: java, pentaho, tomcat8, catalina, pentaho-cde

We use the BI server from Pentaho (Community ed.). Since we have to change the Java-JRE from Oracle to the Opend JDK from Amazon Coretto, there is a problem after starting the server when a user wants to log in (empty page). The login page itself is showing normally - if there is a correct login the described problem occures.

Windows Server 2012 R2
Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212
pentaho-server-ce-8.2.0.0-342

Tried to include .jar files missing, reinstall, local install - nothing worked. Therefore, we have attached the whole Catalina and access-log from last "normal trial" to get a lean output.

**Log Catalina:**

27-May-2019 14:32:25.018 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
27-May-2019 14:32:25.018 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-May-2019 14:32:25.112 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-May-2019 14:32:25.143 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
27-May-2019 14:32:26.033 INFO [FelixShutdown] org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl.unregister unregistering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=pentaho-metaverse-web-cxf590120556,type=Bus.Service.Endpoint,service="{http://service.metaverse.pentaho.org/}MetaverseService",port="MetaverseService",instance.id=1796025488
27-May-2019 14:32:26.033 INFO [FelixShutdown] org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl.unregister unregistering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=pentaho-metaverse-web-cxf590120556,WorkQueueManager=Bus.WorkQueueManager,type=WorkQueueManager,instance.id=531601800
27-May-2019 14:32:26.033 INFO [FelixShutdown] org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl.unregister unregistering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=pentaho-metaverse-web-cxf590120556,type=Bus,instance.id=590120556
27-May-2019 14:32:26.596 INFO [FelixShutdown] org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl.unregister unregistering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=get-fields-core-cxf634285651,type=Bus.Service.Endpoint,service="{http://endpoint.getfields.pentaho.org/}GetFieldsEndpoint",port="GetFieldsEndpoint",instance.id=1950245397

[...]

org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Failed to retrieve object with key [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Failed to retrieve object with key [ApplicationContext].]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
27-May-2019 14:32:27.658 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [pentaho] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3da0db51]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen des Objekts mit Schlüssel [ApplicationContext]., org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ObjectFactoryException: Fehler beim Abrufen

[...]

Rest of file-log: https://ufile.io/8wtti6pm

Comment: The logs you included in the question are after the server started to shutdown (because "A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port"). Do you have anything before that? Did you intend to shutdown the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenJDK is supported by Pentaho 8.2, but it looks like Amazon Corretto is not compatible for whatever reason. There are differences between Amazon Corretto and standard OpenJDk; those differences must be causing the issues you're seeing.

[Differences Amazon Corretto and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305934/differences-amazon-corretto-and-openjdk)

Comment: We changed it to OpenJDK. It re-run after an update by Pentaho (so take the latest version).