# Why one should go for Oracle JDK when Open JDK exists?

Tags: java

I would like To know if it is OK to stay with Open JDK when Oracle JDK exists. Is there any security lapse when going for Open JDK like constant updates to Security will be missed when going for free JDK?

Please clarify.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk