# End of Public Updates for Oracle JDK 8, what is the meaning of that?

Tags: java

According to [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html), Can we say that starting in January 2019, Java is no longer open source?

Comment: No, Java is still open source.

Comment: This has been covered many times already. Search Stack Overflow before posting. Also, the business practices of a vendor and their licensing terms is off-topic. Tip: Search for the white paper titled *Java Is Still Free* for lengthy discussion and details.

Comment: https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/do-not-fall-into-oracles-java-11-trap.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the business practices and licensing terms of a vendor, not a programming problem.

Comment: I asked, I did not understand. indeed this is not a programming problem, but in my opinion this is the basic thing we must pay attention to earlier. Thanks.

Comment: "No public updates" only means that Oracle will not be releasing any more free / public bug fixes, because JDK 8 is obsolete. You should upgrade to a newer version. This has nothing to do with whether Java is open source or not.

Answer (score 2):

Java from Oracle never has been OpenSource.

There exists an OpenJDK which always has been.
You just choose one of the magnifold of builds of the OpenJDK (built by Alibaba, Amazon, IBM, Adopt, ...)

This might help: [Differences between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk)

Comment: A little bit misleading since Oracle is a major contributor to OpenJDK. Read the FAQ https://openjdk.java.net/faq/