# Java SE 11.0.5 (LTS) license (download the latest openJDK updates)

Tags: java

Is jdk downloaded from oracle through the following link is under GPL license, as I thought it's not
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

and if it's not GPL licensed, why the openjdk site is recommending that I download jdk from oracle and claiming that it's under GPL license https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11

> These binaries are provided for use by implementers of the Java SE 11 Platform Specification and are for reference purposes only. This Reference Implementation has been approved through the Java Community Process. Production-ready binaries under the GPL are available from Oracle; and will be in most popular Linux distributions

Comment: There's a nice link to https://www.oracle.com/downloads/licenses/oracle-javase-license.html in the page you linked to.

Comment: java is not open source now

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni what Java are you talking about? Because OpenJDK definitely is.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca same link is available for jdk 8 which is under GPL
it doesn't say which versions are GPL and which are not

Comment: If you want the open source version of Java go here https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: @Mina You seem a bit confused about licenses and OpenJDK vs oracle jdk. Oracle JDK is not and never was open source. OpenJDK is.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Yes :)

Comment: This Link will help you more to understand diff between oracle jdk and OpenJDK

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk

Comment: Where can I find openjdk downloads prior to 11.0.2 (build 11.0.2+9) on https://jdk.java.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Download openJDK and its latest updates from https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Oracle JDK is not GPL

Thanks a million @bhspencer

**Long answer**

I was looking for the updated openJDK 11 at https://jdk.java.net/ or at https://openjdk.java.net/

but both links don't provide clear download links for openJDK latest updates.

A lead can be found here https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk-updates/ that led me to double check that https://adoptopenjdk.net/ is the right place to download from

Again thanks a lot @bhspencer

Answer (score 1):

You see before downloading the JDK from the URL https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

you need to accept their  Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE that binary is not under GPL if you accepted it (it's a trap from Oracle)

the page does provide a binary that is provided under the GPL but it is somewhat hidden in that page this is the link that they provide https://jdk.java.net/

Comment: Same thing with jdk 8 why is it different with 11,
at https://jdk.java.net/ they say that I should get the GPL release from oracle site "Production-ready binaries under the GPL are available from Oracle; and will be in most popular Linux distributions"