# In JDK11 where is the difference between Oracle's source code and openJDK's source code

Tags: java, java-11

What is the difference  between Oracle's source code and openJDK's source code?
I have seen this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk), but what are the differences between the source codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any source differences; there's only one source tree.

The difference lies in the support contract (and occasionally, the Oracle JDK packs in a few more external things, generally because they aren't open source, naturally, you can't find the source tree of these addons, though oracle is working on reducing this to zero.

For example, [*Flight Recorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder) was part of Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK originally, but has been [part of OpenJDK since Java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328).

Comment: Oracle does reserve the right to distribute to its paying customers an urgent fix that has yet to wind its way through the OpenJDK process. So in that small way there may occasionally be a difference between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. Ditto for all the other JDK vendors who use the OpenJDK codebase, such as Azul Systems, Red Hat/IBM, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely, I see the difference between them